# What's wrong on taking this XML element?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

XML:

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
    ...
   <author>
      <name>Seamless</name>
      <uri>https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/SeamlessR</uri>
   </author>
```

Code:

```
var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
var name = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "entry").First().Element("author").Element("name").Value;
```

it says `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Have you gone through the debugger to see what exactly is `NULL`?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: No, it will be using the `XName +(XNamespace, string)` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `Element("author")` and `Element("name")` as if they're not in a namespace. The namespace will have been defaulted to the same namespace as `entry`, so you want:

```
var ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"; // Just use an implicit conversion
var name = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "entry")
               .First()
               .Element(ns + "author")
               .Element(ns + "name")
               .Value;
```

Comment: Oh, didn't know this before! Thank you!